# Let $M=\Bbb Z^2$ . If $N$ and $P$ internal direct summands of $M$ , then does it follow that $N+P$ is also an internal direct summand of $M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, direct-sum

> Let $M=\Bbb Z^2$ . If $N$ and $P$ internal direct summands of $M$ , then does it follow that $N+P$ is also an internal direct summand of $M$.

My attempt :

$\Bbb Z^2=\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z$. Then $N=P=\Bbb Z$. Then isn't $N+P=M$ ? Then it's not an internal direct summand of $M$.

Is that all ? Perhaps I have misunderstood the question. Please point out mistakes.

Comment: This makes no sense: $N=P=\mathbb{Z}$.  A proper nonzero internal direct summand of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, but you are going to have to explain more clearly what $N$ and $P$ are exactly.  And if you say $N=P\cong \mathbb{Z}$ is an internal direct summand of $M$, then $N+P=N=P$ is an internal direct summand of $M$.  If you say $N+P=M$, then $N+P=M$ is an internal direct summand of $M$ since $M=M\oplus 0$.

Comment: You presumably intended $N=P=\mathbb Z\oplus0$, so that it's a subgroup of $M$. Then your answer is correct.  The question should have said "If $N$ and $P$ are distinct internal direct summands ...." But it didn't say "distinct", so you're OK. For the corrected question requiring $N\neq P$, you have Batominovski's answer, or you can use the possibly easier example where $N$ is generated by $\langle(1,1)\rangle$ and $P$ by $\langle(1,-1)\rangle$, both of which admit a complementary summand generated by $\langle(1,0)\rangle$; the sum $N+P$ has index $2$ in $M$.

Answer (score 1):

Both $N:=\big\langle (1,0)\big\rangle$ and $P:=\big\langle (1,2)\big\rangle$ are internal direct summands of $M=\mathbb{Z}^2$, with a complementary direct summand $\big\langle (0,1)\big\rangle$.  However, $N+P=\mathbb{Z}\times (2\mathbb{Z})$ is not an internal direct summand of $M$.